# How to reduce specific gravity of a brine solution?

Tags: organic-chemistry

We have prepared a brine solution ($\ce{NaCl}$ + water). Its present specific gravity is more than 30 percent. We need to keep the specific gravity between 28 and 30 percent. Should we add more water or $\ce{NaCl}$ to the solution?

Comment: Your units of measurement are cryptic to me. But anyway, if you want your solution to get less dense, add more water.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_gravity), the specific gravity of solutions is found by taking the density of said solution and dividing it by the density of water. Therefore, specific gravity is unit-less. Thus, I assume, you need to find the specific gravity of brine made by 28-30% $\ce{NaCl}$, am I right? If so, I hope, following two charts I extracted from *ResearchGate* (**Table 1 & 2**; Ref.1) may be helpful for finding specific gravity of brine at various percentages and temperatures. Please keep in mind that, those percentages are given in % $w/w$.

**Table 1.** Variation of $\ce{NaCl}$ aqueous solutions density with temperature and $\ce{NaCl}$ concentration
[image: Aq_NaCl-1]

**Table 2.** Variation of $\ce{NaCl}$ aqueous solutions density with temperature and $\ce{NaCl}$ concentration 
[image: Aq_NaCl-2]

Ref.1 also contains a table of calculated densities using a mathematical model.

**References:**

1. Andrei Ionuţ Simion, Cristina-Gabriela Grigoraş, Ana-Maria Roșu, Lucian Gavrilă, “Mathematical modelling of density and viscosity of $\ce{NaCl}$ aqueous solutions,” *Journal of Agroalimentary Processes and Technologies* **2015**, *21(1)*, 41-52 (https://www.journal-of-agroalimentary.ro/admin/articole/58458L8_Vol_21(1)_2015_41_52.pdf).